# angular routing when the routing param has a "\" in it

Tags: angularjs

In my project i am using `$routeProvider` to route from one page to  `mainPage`.The configuration is given below. So whenever the url is like `host:port/MainPage/:X/:Y/:Z it would be redirected to the`mainPage.xhtml`.

The problem is if i have a `\` or `/` in  any of my route params the routing doesn't work .

eg:if value is=Z/z the routing doesn't work. How can i ensure the data with `\` can also be used while routing.

```
MainController.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/MainPage/:id/:subId/:value', {
    templateUrl: '/cg510_analytics/html/mainPage.xhtml',
});
```

Comment: I haven't personally comes across this scenario but I don't believe angular will let you do that. For example if, `:id` was `Z/z` it will interpret `:id` as `Z` and `:subId` as `z`. You could hook into the route change events to manipulate the URL or extract pieces you need maybe. Would it not be a viable solution to make use of query string paramaters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To allow slashes in value parameter you can use this path matcher: */MainPage/:id/:subId/:value**. This means that all characters are eagerly stored in $routeParams under the given name (value) when the route matches.

Example:

```
MainController.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/MainPage/:id/:subId/:value*', {
    templateUrl: '/cg510_analytics/html/mainPage.xhtml',
});
```

For path: /MainPage/123/12/param/with/slashes

```
id = 123;
subId = 12;
value = 'param/with/slashes'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, just like without a single page app having a slash will denote a sub directory. To get around this you'll have to create your urls to be something like this: `/myurl/Z%2Fz/something_else`

Then in your config: `.when('/myurl/:variable/something_else', ...`

Then in your controller:

```
console.log($routeParams.variable); //will output Z%2Fz but....
console.log(decodeURIComponent($routeParams.variable)); //will putput Z/z
```

`decodeURIComponent` is a function native to javascript, just like it's opposite `encodeURIComponent`

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [Angular API reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider), it mentions this.

> - path can contain named groups starting with a colon: e.g. :name. All characters up to the next slash are matched and stored in $routeParams under the given name when the route matches.
> - path can contain named groups starting with a colon and ending with a star: > e.g.:name*. All characters are eagerly stored in $routeParams under the given name when the route matches.
> - path can contain optional named groups with a question mark: e.g.:name?.
>
> For example, routes like /color/:color/largecode/:largecode*\/edit will match /color/brown/largecode/code/with/slashes/edit and extract:
>
> - color: brown
> - largecode: code/with/slashes.